# Spring Security - Access User Cache

Tags: spring, spring-security

Is there a way to access the UserCache in Spring Security? What I'd like to do is to remove the user from the cache on logout. So I'd need to get a reference to the user cache to inject it into my custom logout filter.

Thank you all for your help!

Regards,
Robert